# Can the 2-complex associated to a finitely presented group be triangulated?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let G be a finitely presented group. K is the 2-complex associated to G which is constructed as taught in Algebraic Topology. That is , 1-cells corresponding to generators and 2-cells corresponding to relators.

Now, My goal is to embed K in,to $R^5$.  If K is triangulated, then K is 2-simplicial complex, thus, by [1], it can be embedded into $R^5$. However, not every 2-CW complex can be triangulated, as pointed in [2].

So, my question is, for the case of finitely presented group, Can I embed K to $R^5$?

[1][explicitly embedding a simplicial $d$-complex into $\mathbb{R}^{2d+1}$, or algorithms for doing so](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243678/explicitly-embedding-a-simplicial-d-complex-into-mathbbr2d1-or-algor)
[2]https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01896472.pdf

Comment: "finitely presented group" (unfortunately) usually means "finitely presentable". To refer to $K$, you need to refer to a given finite presentation.

Comment: Anyway, the Cayley 2-complex is a polygonal complex, so it's obvious to triangulate (just split the $(2+n)$-gons into $n$ triangles).

Comment: Algebraically this means to play the game like this: say, given a relation $xyx^2z=yz^{-1}x$, introduce the following new generators and new relations: $xy=g_1$, $g_1x=g_2$, $g_2x=g_3$, $g_3z=g_4$, $yz^{-1}=g_5$, $g_5x=g_4$. This is clearly a finite presentation of the same group, and all relations have form $gg'=g''$ with $g$, $g'$, $g''$ some generators, so that all 2-cells of the corresponding $K$ are triangles.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე An interesting game, but I don´t think this way can be used to answer my question.

Comment: @YCor Yes, I just a little bit messy, it is indeed obviously.Think you.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე this is a distinct question, namely find a Cayley complex made of triangles, and is indeed doable by this simple argument. This explained my first comment, to clarify if the presentation is fixed beforehand, and apparently it's indeed the case.

Comment: @YCor What I wanted to say (and failed to say clearly) is that applying your procedure, the obtained 2-complex is again the one corresponding to a(nother) presentation of the same group and this presentation can be explicitly written down.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე No; at least my procedure, if not done carefully, is not invariant under left translations. It seems to be doable but there are some little issues, for instance if one polygon has a nontrivial stabilizer (this can't occur in the torsion-free case).